# Checking that floating points arguments are correct

Tags: c++, constructor, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I want to write a class representing Markov chain (let's name it `MC`). It has a constructor, which takes the state transition matrix (that is, `vector<vector<double>>`. I suppose, it is a good idea to check it is really a matrix (has the same number of rows and columns) and is really a transition matrix: all the numbers in it are probabilities, that is, no less than `0.0` and no greater than `1.0`, and for every row the sum of its elements is `1.0`. However, there is a problem which arises from floating point limitations: for example, the sum `0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.1` will not be equal to `1.0`, so the check will not be that easy. So I see two possible solutions of that problem:

1. Choose some epsilon and compare with epsilon error. Of course it will now accept some matrices violating the transition matrix property, but in general, if someone occasionally passes some bad data into the constructor, he will get an exception.
2. Don't check anything, rely on the class' user, if he passes something bad, it is completely his fault, and the behavior of the class will be unexpected.

What approach is better and more "real-world"? I like the first, but again, not sure how should I choose epsilon.

Comment: 1st is better. 2nd is real-world and by this I mean that we've got lots of poor code worldwide. Code defensively, if you care. Don't, otherwise.

Comment: Clearly the first option is better, however, I'd suggest adding a subtlety if small deviations from the criteria are likely to be a problem: the constructor could have an option that allows it to store a corrected transition matrix that has one or more of the elements in each row modified so that the sum of the elements is as close to `1.0` as possible. There are precedents for this in popular libraries, e.g. functions that take an array of probabilities `a` and normalise each element of the array to equal `a[i]/sum(a)` to deal with the case where the elements of `a` do not add to `1.0`.

Comment: @simon clearly? Looks clear the other way to my eyes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I find that if faulty input to a function causes the function to throw an exception or crash immediately, that makes it a lot easier to find the bugs that caused the faulty input. If the first sign of a problem doesn't turn up until a long time later, it could take a lot of debugging to find the root cause. Where consistency checking causes too much overhead for production code, I'll turn the checking off for production but, if it doesn't slow things down unduly, I like to keep the checking in the production code too.

Comment: @Simon: What does "faulty" mean?  At what point do you declare something "faulty"?

Comment: @tmyklebu: Given a function (in this case a constructor) that requires that its input meet specified criteria, any input that doesn't meet those criteria is faulty. If the function can determine that the input doesn't meet its requirements and can throw an exception immediately, that seems to me to be a faster way to find out why the input data don't meet the function's requirements than waiting until the function produces some undefined behavior.

Comment: @simon in this scenario it seems impossible to agree on the definition of faulty and when that is so my experience tells me that trying to validate will juat lead to false positives and stroppy users

Comment: @simon *If the function can determine that the input doesn't meet its requirements*. Go ahead then. Write the code that separates good input from bad.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I should say that I think there are many benefits the approach that you've taken in your answer. In particular, where the class doesn't know enough about the way it is going to be used to determine the criteria that its input data should meet, it should certainly leave that decision to the user of the class. It seemed to me, though, that in this case there were some criteria that the class could reasonably expect the input data to satisfy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know enough about exactly the requirements that the inputs to the OP's class would have to satisfy. As I have remarked in another comment, I fully agree with the approach described in tmyklebu's answer when the class does not have sufficient information to separate good input from bad. However, I've spent enough time tracking bugs from their point of appearance back to their point of origin in far-removed pieces of code to want to minimise that experience in the future, whenever possible.

Comment: @simon that's the crux of the matter. It's just not clear what is good and what is bad here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: if *it seems impossible to agree on the definition of faulty*, I'd agree with you that *trying to validate will juat lead to false positives and stroppy users*.

Comment: @Simon: Any notion of "faulty" here is going to have the following problem:  I can take something that is not "faulty," do something entirely reasonable to it, and get something "faulty" out.  That's why you avoid declaring things "faulty."  It's not that we aren't sure where the boundary should be; it's that, if we put such a boundary somewhere, we're making the code more useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the second one.

Your class isn't in the business of summing up lists of floating-point numbers and deciding what's "close enough" to 1 and what isn't.  Your user is.  Your class represents Markov chains.  You won't be able to choose a value of epsilon so that your class represents Markov chains in a useful way.

Think about the operations you're going to implement.  Maybe you're going to have a function that hits a probability distribution on the states of the chain with the chain's transition matrix.  Should that function check whether the input probability distribution is a probability distribution within some epsilon?

Your function almost certainly won't preserve the "is a probability distribution" property; you'll get some drift due to rounding error away from the space of probability distributions as you repeatedly hit your probability distribution by your Markov chain.  You can correct this by normalising afterward, but that causes even more inaccuracy.

Now think about the "given a Markov chain and an integer k, return the Markov chain formed by iterating the input chain k times" operation.  You can see that this will accumulate roundoff and suffer from much the same problems as "hit probability distribution with Markov chain."

Wouldn't it suck if you only had a choice between stuff that breaks after 12 hours of use and stuff that's unnecessarily inaccurate?

(Checking the squareness and matrixness of the square matrix argument is, of course, totally reasonable.)

Comment: +1 the user of your code can't get anywhere if they send bogus inputs so let them take care of getting it right

Comment: Could have a helper function in the class called "check()" or something that gives a "score" (or "true"/"false") result based on whether it is a "good" matrix or not.