# How much to validate in private functions

Tags: java, software-design

I have written the following code, which first validates a matrix and then it would invoke a private function to add them, it validation is a success. Now its a good practice to validate once again in a private function according to effective java. However, if validation step itself is long, do we need to validate everything in the private function ? If not then where to draw the line ?

```
private static void check(int[][] m1, int[][] m2, char op) {
    if (m1 == null || m2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("No input matrix should be null.");
    }
    /**
     * Switch case was thought to be beneficial in case of future extensibility.
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Advantages_and_disadvantages
     */
    switch (op) {
        case 'a' : if (m1.length != m2.length && m1[0].length != m2[0].length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla"); else break;
        case 'm' : if (m1[0].length != m2.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bla bla"); else break;
    }
}

public static int[][] add (int[][] m1, int[][] m2) {
    check (m1, m2, 'a');
    return add(m1, m2, m1.length - 1, m1[0].length - 1);
}

private static int[][] add (int[][] m1, int[][] m2, int rows, int cols) {
    assert m1 != null;
    assert m2 != null;

    // final can be returned check Arrays docjar line 2843.
    final int[][] m = new int[rows + 1][cols + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++ ) {
            m[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Here I have only validated if matrices are null.. but that is useless if I dont validate the other parameters passed. Once again this question is generic so please dont suggest code improvement. This code only serves as an example to a much broader question - how much to validate while calling a private function. Thanks,

Comment: You might find the discussion and answer in [Checking that floating points arguments are correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984406/checking-that-floating-points-arguments-are-correct/15984718#15984718) to be of value. In that discussion, I initially argued for validating wherever possible, but I was convinced by other posters that anything but very basic validation often (maybe always) requires a function to know more about how it is going to be used than it can possibly know.

Comment: In general, I like the paradigm in which programmer check the arguments before using them. I would like to comment something. I think if you have validate the two matrix in check method, you do not have to validate them again. There is a balance between validate and over validate, but this is just my own opinion. Overall, I like this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Validation is one of reasons to split the application / library to layers.

The "public" layer should validate. Usually that's a service layer or API, or, in general, the classes/methods which other developers will call.

Then, in the low-level operations, validation is ommited and the method does expect the input to be already validated. This fact should be mentioned in javadoc.

Related note - I adopted a technique when I first collect the validation violations to a `List` and then report all of them in one exception. This is very convenient for the user so he doesn't have to go through an annoying cycle fix/try/fix/try/fix/try, but rather fix,fix,fix,fix,try.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, explicitly checking for null references and the like (eg different sized matrices) in low level operations constitutes "code bloat". In this example: Validation should be done after each operation which loads or otherwise modifies the STRUCTURE of the matrix... all subsequent operations upon the VALUES in the matrix should presume valid matrices.

I'd also do my "operation specific" validations directly in each operation-method, unless/until the validation code becomes "bulky", in which case I'd factor it out into a separate "validate*Operation*" method.

This is JUST my opinion... based on experience of reporting "bad input" to the user *at the appropriate time*, and helps me to seek destroy my own mistakes during testing and debugging.

Cheers. Keith.

PS: Another alternative is Assertions, which are only active when a "debug flag" is turned on, and not in production where efficiency may be an issue.